# RTMPS and HTTPS support for JWPlayer

Tags: jwplayer, wowza, jwplayer6

I have been using Jwplayer premium version and I'm trying to configure Wowza streamlock addon with Jwplayer. Streamlock addon will deliver the streams via RTMPS and HTTPS, So I'm wondering, is there any possibilities to use JWPlayer with RTMPS or HTTPs to get live streams

or will JWplayer support RTMPS and HTTPS ?

Comment: We support HTTPs, and RTMPe, but not RTMPs...

Comment: thanks. let me check it using https

Comment: Np. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot load m3u8 Crossdomain Access denied" error in the JWplayer screen and wowza's crossdomain.xml is here http://pastebin.com/u4J2fsdM

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running this?

Comment: Here it is http://spcserver.net/player/player4.html, I'm using https with port number 444

Comment: Can you update to 6.8? - https://account.jwplayer.com/

Comment: So, does 6.8 support RTMPs then, is that the reason for the last question?